# OS X Lion Safari Flash plugin issues

Tags: macos, flash, safari

I'm using OS X fully updated and patched, along with Safari.
A few weeks back I started noticing a Flash problem: Every time I load a youtube video, the CPU consumption goes up to 100% on one core and the video tries to load but doesn't until several dozen seconds or sometimes even minutes later.

If I kill Safari the the QTKit process that sandboxes the Flash plugin is still there and usually remains alive for a few seconds, then dies.

I am also running the latest Flash plugin, since it self-updated a few days back.

I really don't know what to do anymore, Flash is simply unusable on Safari (but works fine on Chrome) and I don't know whether reinstalling Safari from scratch would help but I feel a bit uneasy about doing that.

Any ideas to debug the problem?

- OS X 10.7.3 on Intel
- Safari 5.1.5
- No extensions installed on Safari
- Pretty much vanilla OS X, only apps added

Thanks in advance!